# Why <bgsound src="music/binks.mp3"/> is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, project

I want to play some background music in my own website , I've been searching for 15 minutes and everything seems outdated.
Can someone help me?

```html
<body>
  <bgsound src="music/binks.mp3"/>  
</body>
```

`<bgsound src="music/binks.mp3"/>`  ->>> THIS seems to me outdated , and its not working

Comment: `bgsound` is already removed in most modern browsers as it's [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/bgsound).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/bgsound

Comment: As stated in documentation: _Warning: Do not use this! In order to embed audio in a Web page, you should be using the `<audio>` element._

Comment: Have you tried `<audio>`?

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to use something like `<audio>`:

```
<audio id="background-music" src="path/to/music.mp3" loop></audio>
```

And then the following in a js file or in a script tag to play the music.

```
const music = document.getElementById("background-music");
music.play();
```

Do keep in mind most browser have autoplay policy now, so often the sound will be blocked.

Comment: There is [`autoplay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide) attribute

Comment: Do note that most browsers don't allow you to play audio without the user first interacting with the page. (I.e. you can't play music directly after opening it.)

Comment: Correct as @Ivar says, often browsers will stop it from playing due to autoplay policy, but in that case you can always add a button.

Comment: why not ivar ? i want exactly like that

Comment: @SaulSousa [Because it is annoying](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/).

Comment: i want the music exactly to start when the page is opended

Comment: Unsure of any workarounds for that.
Possibly calling the play at a slightly later state or set it to play after a user interaction such as scrolling.

Comment: @SaulSousa You may want it but users don't necessarily want that, it's annoying, and that's why it's mostly not allowed anymore. If you think the user wants the sound, you can always add a button "enable sound" which will then be allowed.